# "Does that mean to kill" or "does that mean killing", Which one is the proper one, and why?

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

Should I say:

> What is the English translation of 'ermorden', does it mean ***"to kill"***?
>
> What is the English translation of 'ermorden', does it mean ***"killing"***?

I don't know which one to use, although ***"Does it mean to kill?"*** seems the right one, I feel like I'm missing something. May you guys tell me which one is grammatically correct and why?

Comment: This "to do" and "doing" thing haunts me

Comment: I feel like what you're missing most is **more context**. It's not really fair to native speakers to ask: _Which one sounds better?_ when there is no surrounding context. If I'm asking about a word I don't understand, I might say it like this: "What does 'to murder' mean? Does that mean 'to kill'?" But if I were asking about something else, I might say it differently. For example, to my uncle (assuming he is deeply involved in organized crime): "What do you mean, we're going to 'take care of' Bill? Does that mean killing?" See [Details, please](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439).

Comment: @J.R. I don't think that OP is asking how to translate *ermorden*--what he's asking is how to *ask* how to translate an infinitive.

Comment: @StoneyB - That's more evident now, but when I left my comment, the question read like [this](http://ell.stackexchange.com/revisions/5c534a33-87ed-497a-b5c3-0df5003b8448/view-source).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a general context we would ask this using the infinitive (either marked with *to* or unmarked), since that's generally regarded as the 'base' form of a verb.

> What is the English translation of 'ermorden'? Does it mean "to kill"? OR
>   What is the English translation of 'ermorden'? Does it mean "kill"? <sup>†</sup>

In some specific contexts, however, things get a little more complicated, because both the infinitive *(to) kill* and the gerund-participle *killing* may be appropriate translation of *ermorden* employed as a nominal designating the act or practice of killing.

> "Kleine Kinder ermorden ist schließlich das schlimmste und gemeinste." How should I translate *ermorden* here? Would "to kill" or "killing" express the sense more accurately?

<sup>†</sup>And in a general context the answer to both of these is "Probably not"—*ermorden* will usually call for a stronger translation as *murder* or in some circumstances *assassinate*—or as a nominal, *assassination*.

Comment: In "Kleine Kinder ermorden" ermorden starts with a lowercase letter, so it is an infinitive and translates as "to kill small children". If it were "Kleiner Kinder Ermorden" - Ermorden starting with a capital letter- it would be a noun, specifically a gerund, and would translate as "Killing small children". http://germanforenglishspeakers.com/verbs/present-participles-and-gerunds/

Comment: @JavaLatte does the fact of the first letter being capital or not alters the meaning? wow, how do you differentiate while speaking?

Comment: @Mr.Derpinthoughton, i think that's a question for a German to answer :-)

Answer (score 5):

The word ermorden is an German infinitive. In English, you make a verb into an infinitive  by putting the word "to" in front it, and you make a noun (Ermorden with a capital E) or an active participle by putting "-ing" on the end of it. So, it you want to ask for the exact meaning, you would ask

> What is the English translation of 'ermorden': does it mean "to kill"?

and the answer would be

> "Nearly right... a better translation would be "to assassinate" or "to murder".

For more information about gerunds (verbal nouns), participles and infinitives, see [here](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/627/01/)

Comment: Nearly but not quite--the *-ing* form may also represent a gerund with nominal function: *Killing women and children was regarded as unmanly*.

Comment: A gerund is a noun. In German, nouns start with a capital letter. In the example, ermorden starts with a small letter:  it is an infinitive. Nearly but not quite, yes. :-)

Comment: But English makes only a syntactic distinction, not an orthographic one. *Killing women and small children* is a clause headed by a verb, the gerund-participle *killing*; the nounier version of the gerund-participle (some but not all call it a 'verbal noun' here) would be *the killing **of** women and children*.

Comment: As @StoneyB says, Gerunds really aren't nouns. They are verbs heading clauses which do the job of Subject or Object in a clause, or Object of a preposition. Gerunds can have Objects for example, but nouns cannot. Gerunds can be modified by adverbs, but nouns cannot. So gerunds do jobs that we associate with noun phrases, but they are not noun phrases or nouns.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the context. It's perfectly acceptable to ask:

> *What is the English translation of 'ermorden', does it mean 'to kill'?*